# Convert variable input formats to black and white MP4

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently using an FFMPEG command like:

ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf scale=1920:1080 output.mp4

to convert varying input format file to a fixed resolution MP4 output file.  One final step I need is to make the output Black and White (the input files will be full color).

I have tried both 
    -pix_fmt gray 
and
    -vf format=gray,format=yuv422p

but both just result in a black output video.

After much trawling of google, it looks like the FFMPEG exe I downloaded (for windows) wasn't compiled with the "-enable-gray" option, but I don't know if this makes any difference and don't know how to obtain a windows FFMPEG with this option enabled (building FFMPEG myself looks like a lot of hard work).
Any advice welcome!  Thanks.

PS I should add that the conversion I'm currently doing and any grayscale conversion could be separate steps if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do need a ffmpeg build with gray pixel format enabled. You should get your binary from the Windows link at [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Download the latest 32-bit static build.

You can check if your build has gray enabled by running

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts | findstr /r gray
```

It should list an entry for gray.

And use `format=gray` in your `vf` chain and `-pix_fmt yuv420p` together for broad compatibility.

> The command below is for linux. [`grep`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) will work as [`findstr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)!
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -pix_fmts | grep -i gray
> ```

Comment: Running your command on my current FFMPEG results in 
  IO... gray                   1             8
  IO... gray16be               1            16
  IO... gray16le               1            16
Does this mean it has gray enabled?

Comment: Ok, just follow the last line of my answer. Should work with your current build.

Comment: Running the command 
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf format=gray -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
results in a black screen.  I wonder if trying to do the conversion from .mov to mp4 at the same time is the problem? Now I think of it I'll try separate commands

Comment: Separating out the conversion from .mov -> .mp4 and the conversion to grayscale (using your commands) worked. Thanks :)